# Google Chrome Bookmark Synch overwrote my bookmarks--how can I get them back?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

This is a strange one.

I have had bookmark synching turned on for two OS X machines for some months now. Today, I noticed that my bookmarks have disappeared. It seems that an older version of the bookmark folders on my Home computer have overwritten my bookmarks on my Work computer.

Is there a revision history for bookmark synchs somewhere? How can I get my old bookmarks back?

Comment: Nope. You're out of luck. Use Google Bookmarks or XMarks for cloud-stored bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

My research shows (in Windows 7) Chrome stores our bookmarks in a "file" file called "bookmarks" at:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Fortunately when Chrome Syncs it creates "bookmarks.bak". I intend to merge the two somehow, but I digress.

In this case:

1. Close Chrome
2. Change "bookmarks" to "bookmarks.home"
3. Change "bookmarks.bak" to "bookmarks"
4. Relaunch Chrome!

Hope this helps someone!